# Why live() not working with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I write this code.

But I don't know why it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_lang").live("click", function() {
        var string = $(this).attr("value");
        var delete_from = "languges";
        var data_id = $(this).attr("data");
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/ajax_service.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                "string": string,
                "content": delete_from,
                "ajax_service": "delete_string"
            },
            success: function(reslangdel) {
                console.log(reslangdel);
                if (reslangdel.error == true) {
                    alert("حدث خطأ المرجو المحاولة لاحقا !");
                }
                if (reslangdel.success === true) {
                    $(".lang_elm_" + data_id + "").remove();
                }
            },
            error: function(reslangdelError) {
                alert("حدث خطأ المرجو المحاولة لاحقا !");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Why is this code not working?

Comment: @Mourand Kaaroundi what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @HenryDev I use jQuery v3.0.0

Comment: Time to learn to look in browser console for errors and report them in questions. Should be seeing something to effect of *"live is not a function"*

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your ajax you should specify the dataType by adding:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Also, **live** was deprecated. You can use **on** instead, but If you persist on using **live** Try using: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: if proper contentType header is set the dataType shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Answer should also include migration to using `on()` , not recommending downgrading jQuery

Comment: Correction, `live()` was deprecated in v1.7 and **removed** in v1.9